# How to resolve conflicts for a protected branch ,Github

Tags: git, github

We have 2 branches, `master` and `feature`. We base off all the other branches from `feature` branch. After a while, we merge a bunch of `PRs`to `feature` and finally we merge `feature` to `master`. Now, our `feature` branch has lots of commits that need to be merged to `master`. But, there are a lot of conflicts on `Github`. `feature` branch is protected and can't be pushed directly. So, I followed these steps to resolve conflicts

1. Created a branch `resolve-conflicts` based off of `feature`
2. Merge master to `resolve-conflicts` locally
3. Resolve the conflicts
4. Created a PR against `feature` branch ( Merge `resolve-conflicts` to `feature` )
5. Merge

Now, the PR where I resolved conflicts was now merged to `feature` branch. I was hoping merging `feature` to `master` should now be possible. But, it's still giving the same conflicts as before. Nothing changed.

My desired outcome is to resolve conflicts for the protected branch without directly pushing

Answer (score 0):

As [@Priya said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197786/3012550), your process sounds like it should work.

Since it should work but it doesn't work, you may benefit from reproducing the GitHub conflict locally to see if there is something you're missing.

I suggest the following debugging approach:

1. Pull the latest `master` and `feature` locally
2. Attempt to merge from `feature` to `master`
3. either it works or it doesn't

   - if it does work, then you can answer "why did this work locally but not in GitHub?"
   - if it does not work, then you can repeat your procedure locally (new branch off of `feature`, merge in `master`, merge your new branch to `feature`, attempt to merge feature to `master`).

Probably this will either (1) make it obvious what you're missing, or (2) allow you to ask a more specific question that might lead to an answer.

When you're finished your experimenting, you can `reset --hard` to `origin/master` and `origin/feature` to blow away your experiments and get back to the origin version of those branches. (If you're not familiar with `reset --hard`, be advised: it's not easy to undo. Proceed with caution.)

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout feature
git reset --hard origin/feature
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new branch for conflict resolution: This is what you've already done. Create a branch (e.g., resolve-conflicts) based off of the feature branch.

Merge master into resolve-conflicts locally: Pull the latest changes from the master branch into your resolve-conflicts branch. This ensures that you have the most up-to-date code from master to resolve conflicts against.

```
git checkout resolve-conflicts
git merge master
```

Resolve conflicts: Now that you have the changes from master in your resolve-conflicts branch, you need to resolve any conflicts in your code. Use your preferred method or editor to resolve these conflicts.

Commit the resolved changes: After resolving conflicts, stage the changes and commit them.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Resolved conflicts with master branch"
```

Push the resolve-conflicts branch: Push your resolve-conflicts branch to the remote repository.

```
git push origin resolve-conflicts
```

Create a pull request against the feature branch: On GitHub, create a pull request to merge the resolve-conflicts branch into the feature branch.

Merge the pull request: After the pull request is reviewed and approved, merge it into the feature branch.

Attempt to merge feature branch into master: Now, try merging the feature branch into the master branch. Since you've already resolved conflicts in the feature branch, this step should ideally proceed smoothly.

Comment: Than you for your response. Not sure if I had missed anything. But, this is exactly what I did and when I tried to merge `feature` branch to `master`, Github was still giving me conflicts